# Solr HBase search engine

Tags: hadoop, search, solr, hbase, hdfs

I need to use `SolrCloud` as the search engine on top of `HBase` and `HDFS` for searching a very large num of documents.

Currently these docs are in different data sources. I am getting confused whether Solr should search, index and store these docs within itself or Solr should just be used for indexing and docs along with their metadata of the docs should reside in HBAse/HDFS layer.

I have tried searching how the Solr HBase integration works best (meaning what should be done at the Solr level and what at the Hadoop level) but in vain. Anyone has done this kind of Big Data search earlier and can give some pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solr provides fast search via its indexes. Solr uses **inverted indexes** for this. So, you [index](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Indexing+and+Basic+Data+Operations) documents to solr, it creates the indexes. Based on how you have defined the schema.xml, solr decides how the indexes has to be created. The indexes and the field values are stored in HDFS (based on your config in **solrconfig.xml**)

With respect to Hbase, you can directly query run you query on hbase without having to use Solr. [SolrBase](https://github.com/Photobucket/Solbase) is an SOLR and Hbase integration available. Also have a look at [liliy](http://www.lilyproject.org/lily/index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Is it better to have one big index or multiple indexes?

Comment: its based on how you want to do the search. It is always advisable to index only those fields which you are going to use as filter in your query.

Answer (score 1):

The good design followed is search for things in solr, get the id of the records quickly, and then if needed, fetch the entire record from Hbase. You need to make sure that entire data is there in hbase, and only sufficient data is indexed. Needless to say that both solr and hbase should be in sync. One ready made framework, is NGDATA/hbase indexer [here](https://github.com/NGDATA/hbase-indexer/wiki).

Solr works wonders to get the counts, grouping counts, stats. So once you get those numbers and their id's, Hbase can take over. once u have row key in hbase(id), you get low latency search results, that suits well with web applications too

Comment: Thanks,  that's very helpful.  If a subset of the matched docs need to be shown based on user permissions,  then should that filtering take place at the solr level or while querying hbase

Comment: too many things here. Subset of matched docs - Are they coming from hbase? Mostly once the id is fetched from solr, you go to hbase for fetching entire record. With this design, I can see that, the user permissions come at Hbase level. I suppose you are talking about admin and user kind of permissions. If yes, why to categorize data based on permissions. I think, the events generated at web level should take care it. Correct me if I am wrong